# low events conditional to show event date that lasts for more than one day

Tags: low, low-events

I am using low events for my calendar. 
I am trying to find conditional that will allow me to show both my event start date and event closing date when my event lasts more than one day and just the start date when the event is only on one day.

So in the code below showing the start and end_date means if the event is only on one day we see that date twice.I need an conditional to apply to the end_date code section which is based on the event being more than one day.

Thanks for any help

```
            <figcaption class="news-event__caption">
                <time itemprop="startDate" content="{event_date:start_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}" datetime="{event_date:start_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}">
                    <span class="day">{event_date:start_date format="%d"}</span>
                    <span class="month">{event_date:start_date format="%F"} </span>
                     <span class="day"> {event_date:end_date format="%d" }</span>
                     <span class="month">{event_date:end_date format="%F"}</span>
                     </time>    
            </figcaption>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [the :one_day modifier](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-events/docs/fieldtype#one-day).

```
{if '{event_date:one_day}' != 'y'} Show stuff for multiple days {/if}
```